# Why is iText failing to extract this text?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Text extracted from this PDF file, using iTextSharp (v. 5.5.6) with either strategy, is missing the headers (shown in bold):

http://www.in.gov/legislative/iac/T03290/A00031.PDF

Also, during the extraction (around page 40 IIRC), I received an exception:

```
Unable to handle Content of type iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary
```

I worked around the exception by adding code to `GetContentBytesFromContentObject` to ignore `PdfDictionary` objects, but I'm still at a loss on how to extract the text properly.

I strongly suspect the problem is that the missing text is part of the Bookmarks outline of the PDF, and `GetTextFromPage()` doesn't know how to deal with bookmarks and certainly doesn't know how to put the bookmark text in with the rest of the text.

Can anyone confirm that this is the problem? Is there a workaround?

Here's another URL that is extracting without issues, it has bookmarks as well:

http://www.in.gov/legislative/iac/T03290/A00010.PDF

I don't have control over the PDFs, they are produced by a government agency.

Comment: Since iText v5 is a supported commercial product, why not ask the iText support list for assistance.

Comment: Kevin, the support staff have specifically requested that SO be used for questions rather than the email list (which I do subscribe to). This product is dual-licensed AGPL and commercial, and many users (including myself) don't fit under the commercial use.

Comment: @Kevin iText is available either under a commercial license or under the AGPL. iText customer support is available for commercial licensees only, the open support takes place on stack overflow.

Comment: I have tested the example with the version of iText that is under development. I can't reproduce the problem. So either we've fixed this problem since iText 5.5.6 was released, or something else is at play.